# Name output features based on the input parameters with Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, expression

I am working on a script to parse out features in a .gdb and am having troubles getting the correct naming for the output features. Here's the stripped code for reference:

```
# Set the workspace   
env = "C:/Path/to/my/wd"
ap.env.workspace = env   

for child in Path(env).iterdir():
    if child.is_dir() and '.gdb' in child.name:               
        #Set parameters
        Input_Features = fr'{env}\\.gdb\\feature'                   
        Group_By_Fields = "ASSIGNMENT_ID"
        Output_Location = fr'{env}\\.gdb'

        Output_Feature_Class_2 = fr'feature_*Value*'        

        ap.env.overwriteOutput = False
        Selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION"           

        for Selected_Features, Value in (Input_Features, Group_By_Fields):
            # Select Layer by Attribute
            Output_Layer_Name = ap.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(
                in_layer_or_view=Input_Features,
                selection_type=Selection_type,
                where_clause="",
                invert_where_clause=""
                )   

            # Feature Class to Feature Class
            Output_Feature_Class = ap.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(
                in_features=Output_Layer_Name,
                out_path=Output_Location,
                out_name=Output_Feature_Class_2,                    
                )
```

Results in

```
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
Error000354: The name includes invalid characters
Failed to execute (FeatureClasstoFeatureClass).
```

I'm assuming the invalid character is the "*" (I've also tried "%" and "?") I used in Output_Feature_Class_2.

The goal is basically to group by ASSIGNMENT_ID, and then run FeatureClasstoFeatureClass on each grouping with the output names being "input_ABC", "input_XYZ", etc. where ABC/XYZ is the assignment_id that each feature class was grouped by. The first part (Select Layer by Attribute) of the loop presently works or at least produces an output.

As I'm looking at it now, I think it may be an issue with the "where" I'm trying to bring in the prompt. The [sample code](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) suggests delimitedField and expression parameters which might be what I need to toy with.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things wrong with your code is that you are assigning the Output_Feature_Class_2 too early. It should be inside the for Selected_Features … loop, then the Output_Feature_Class_2 will change with every change in value.

Build the Output_Feature_Class_2 name like this:

```
Output_Feature_Class_2 = f'feature_{Value}'
```

And for safety validate the name:

```
Output_Feature_Class_2 = arcpy.ValidateTableName(Output_Feature_Class_2 , Output_Location)
```